# How to turn a random int into a String for use in if/else?

Tags: java, string, if-statement, int

So I'm writing a program for my AP Comp Sci class and I need some help with parsing ints and such.

How do I take a random integer and turn it into a string that can be used inside an `if`/`else` statement?

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.awt.Container;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.lang.*;
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

class LibraryGUI {

// variables and objects
JFrame frame, frame2, frame3;
JPanel panel, panel2, panel3;
JLabel label, label2, label3, label4;
JButton button1;
JButton button2, button3, enter2;
JTextField username, logincred;

Random r = new Random();

public LibraryGUI()
{
    frame = new JFrame("LexCorp Library");
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    label = new JLabel("Welcome to LexCorp Library");

    button1 = new JButton("Login");
    button1.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
            frame3 = new JFrame("Find Account");
            panel3 = new JPanel();
            enter2 = new JButton("Enter");
            frame3.setLayout(new GridLayout(1,1));

            panel3.setBackground(Color.white);
            panel3.setSize(700,700);

            label4 = new JLabel("Enter account number");
            logincred = new JTextField("\t\t");

            logincred.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent j){
                    String choose = logincred.getText();
                }
            });

            panel3.add(label4);
            panel3.add(logincred);
            panel3.add(enter2);

            frame3.getContentPane().add (panel3);

            frame3.pack();
            frame3.setVisible(true);

            //internalcode
        }
    });

    button2 = new JButton("Make a new Account");
    button2.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent f){
            //GUI Section
            frame2 = new JFrame("Make a new account");
            //frame2.setLayout(new GridLayout(4,4));
            panel2 = new JPanel();

            panel2.setLayout(new GridLayout(4,3));
            //panel2.setLayout(new FlowLayout());

            label2 = new JLabel("Account's name");
            username = new JTextField();

            int acc = r.nextInt(1000);

            label3 = new JLabel("Your account number is " +acc);

            button3 = new JButton("Enter");
            button3.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ent){
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(frame, "Account Created");
                    frame2.dispose();
                }
            });

            panel2.add(label2);

            panel2.add(username);
            panel2.add(button3);
            panel2.add(label3);

            frame2.pack();

            username.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae){
                    String user = username.getText();
                    System.out.println(user);
                }
            });

            panel2.setSize(700,700);
            panel2.setBackground(Color.LIGHT_GRAY);

            frame2.getContentPane().add (panel2);
            frame2.pack();
            frame2.setVisible(true);

            //internalCode
        }
    });

    //panel properties
    panel = new JPanel();
    panel.setSize(700,700);
    panel.setLayout(new GridLayout(10,10));
    panel.setBackground(Color.yellow);

    //add-ins
    panel.add(label);
    panel.add(button1);
    panel.add(button2);

    frame.getContentPane().add (panel);
}

    public void display()
    {
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Comment: *"how do i do this???"* - Documentation and research is a good place to start.  Something like `Integer.toString` will allow you to convert an `int` to a `String`

Comment: _I need some help with parsing ints and such_ Then you shouldn't be posting code related to GUIs, unless it directly affects your question.

Comment: You could also just do following: String str = "" + [integer variable name]

Comment: "" + r  (adds r to an empty string)

Comment: Honestly, I see `"" + n` a lot and it makes my skin crawl, I don't know why, it just does.  Generally `Integer.toString` is more efficiently, especially if you're doing this kind of thing in loops, but even `new StringBuilder().append(n).toString()` would seem more efficient, but maybe I'm just been an old fuddy duddy...

Comment: BTW - A single blank line of white space in source code is all that is *ever* needed.  Blank lines after `{` or before `}` are also typically redundant.

Answer (score 1):

> (take an..) integer and turn it into a string that can be used inside an IF ElSE

How about instead ***don't convert it?***  The conditions of an `if` statement can work with integers, and do it more easily than strings!

### E.G.

```
int x = random.nextInt(100); 
if (x < 50) { 
    //..
```

Answer (score 0):

if an int primitive type goes with a string, then the result will be a string. 
for example,

int b=3;

String bs = b+"";

then the bs will be "3"

If you are interested in programming, I will suggest you to read "Think in Java." Reading it helps me a lot.

Comment: Honestly, I see `"" + n` a lot and it makes my skin crawl, I don't know why, it just does.  Generally `Integer.toString` is more efficiently, especially if you're doing this kind of thing in loops, but even `new StringBuilder().append(n).toString()` would seem more efficient, but maybe I'm just been an old fuddy duddy...

Comment: Sure, StringBuilder approach will be more efficient, but here in the question, it's just one line of code(acc), there's no for loop...I think it's no big deal.

Comment: Except you're creating at least 2 temporary `String` objects (I could be mistaken and they might be optimised by the compiler) and encouraging bad habits.  `Integer.toString` is only one line...Like I said, it's just something that grinds on me :P

Comment: well, you are correct. I can't argue with that ~ 　：）

Comment: `"" + n` compiles to `new StringBuilder().append(n).toString()` which creates 1 unnecessary `StringBuilder` which contains 1 unnecessary `char[]` (except in some versions: https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-6219959). And if `n` was compile time constant and the compiler knew how the String will look at runtime (i.e. `n` is final) then `"" + n` would compiles to `"5"` (or whatever `n`) directly. when there is nothing to concatenate to, use `Integer.toString`/`String.valueOf`, if there is, just `+`. `+` is mostly the right thing to do, loops (and this here)are the most prominent exception.

Answer (score 0):

Please use:

```
Integer.toString(int)
```

and not:

```
int + ""
```

It is the more elegant way and also easier to process by the JVM. It is not a complex operation either way but is the correct way to do it.